# mudblazor - daterange picker

Tags: mudblazor

This is my code for the dateranger picker.

```
<MudDateRangePicker Label="Date Ranges" @bind-DateRange="callfunction(record)" />

private DateRange callfunction(SEQuestionnaire record)
    {
        return new DateRange(record.DataCalendar1, record.DataCalendar2);
    }
```

But I get an error saying
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer        331 217

Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type     332 217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a `@bind` directive on a function. Use the `DateRange` property and `DateRangeChanged` EventCallback for custom logic.

Make sure your `SEQuestionnaire.DataCalendar1` are of type, nullable `DateTime?`

```
<MudDateRangePicker Label="Basic range picker" DateRange="_dateRange" DateRangeChanged="(e)=>HandleDateRangeChange(e,_record)" />

@code { 
    private MyRecord _record ;
    private DateRange _dateRange;
    List<string> passedChange = new();
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _record = new (){dt1=DateTime.Now.Date, dt2=DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).Date};
        _dateRange =  new DateRange(_record.dt1,_record.dt2);
    }
    void HandleDateRangeChange(DateRange newDateRange,MyRecord passedRecord)
    {
        // do something with passedRecord
        passedChange.Add(passedRecord.dt1.ToString());

        // or change the existing record
        _record.dt1 = newDateRange.Start;
        _record.dt2 = newDateRange.End;

        // make sure to change the original field that is on DateRange
        _dateRange = newDateRange;
    }
    public class MyRecord{
        public DateTime? dt1 {get;set;}
        public DateTime? dt2 {get;set;}
    }
}
```